# Change icon for wall photo post

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

can I change icon for photo uploaded by my app to the Facebook?
I already set up icon in the app preferences but it doesn't make any difference - app uploaded with standard icon: [image]

Or may be I can change icon only for "posts" but not for photo uploads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set both small and large icons in the facebook developer app preferences. By doing so I was able to achieve changing the post app icon.

Cheers

Comment: Both logos were set. Did you tried to post photo or just normal post?

Comment: I posted a picture and it worked just fine. Perhaps you could paste some of your code...